# Is this a net time for transporting a file?

Tags: java, android, io

I made an app to calculate file transporting time.

Here is my code:

```
for (File srcfile : fList) {

        srcFileName = srcfile.getName();
        sizeInMB = (srcfile.length() / (1024*1024));
        srcFilePath = srcPath + "/" + srcFileName;

        try
        {
            fis = new FileInputStream(srcFilePath);

            tmp = fis.available();
            bufDynmc = new byte[tmp];

            while (true)
            {
                readStartTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                bytesRead = fis.read(bufDynmc);
                readEndTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

                readTimeSum += (readEndTime - readStartTime);

                if (bytesRead > 0)
                {
                    if(rsltCode == RESULT_OK)
                    {
                        treeUri = rsltData.getData();
                        DocumentFile pickedDir = DocumentFile.fromTreeUri(this, treeUri);
                        DocumentFile newFile = pickedDir.createFile("image/jpg", srcFileName);

                        fos = getContentResolver().openOutputStream(newFile.getUri());

                        writeStartTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                        fos.write(bufDynmc, 0, bytesRead);
                        writeEndTIme = System.currentTimeMillis();

                        writeTimeSum += (writeEndTIme - writeStartTime);

                    }

                    continue;
                } else break;
            }
            sizeSum += sizeInMB;
            fis.close(); fos.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {e.printStackTrace();}

        rescanGallery(treeUri);
    }
```

What I want to measure is how much time has been spend from source directory to RAM ,
and from RAM to destination directory.

Am I measuring the reading time and writing time with right method?
I'm not sure cuz this program gives me a time which is too fast.

Comment: Have you tried TraceView? http://developer.android.com/tools/performance/traceview/index.html It will show you how much time was spent executing a particular method.